# Pandas Custom Cumcount

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, running-count

I am trying to cumulative count the column `Value` grouped by the column `User`, but only increasing the count if there have been a different value in between.

The best I was able to achieve was a normal cumcount using:

```
df['Cumcount'] = df.groupby(['User', 'Value'].cumcount()+1
```

```
 User  Value     Cumcount
0      A      X       1
1      A      X       2
2      A      Y       1
3      A      X       3
4      A      Z       1
5      A      Y       2
6      B      X       1
7      B      Y       1
8      B      X       2
9      B      X       3
```

But my desired output would be:

```
  User  Value     Cumcount
0      A      X       1
1      A      X       1
2      A      Y       1
3      A      X       2
4      A      Z       1
5      A      Y       2
6      B      X       1
7      B      Y       1
8      B      X       2
9      B      X       2
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: you're grouping by User and Value, explain why your expected result at index 1 should be A X 1 (again)?

Answer (score 1):

You could set two conditions to create a series that returns `True` and `False` and set it to `s`.

1. The first condition with `.duplicated()` indicates whether or not any of the rows are duplicates.
2. The second condition does a `.groupby('User')` and takes the `.cumcount()` and compares to your version that does the same but by `User` and `Value`. Essentially, if the former is greater than the latter, that means there were values in between.

The combination of 1 and 2 return the the `boolean` series s, which would look like this if you included it as a column in your dataframe:

```
df['s'] = ((df.duplicated(subset=(['User', 'Value'])))
             & (df.groupby('User').cumcount() + 1 > df['Cumcount']))

  User Value  Cumcount      s
0    A     X         1  False
1    A     X         2  False
2    A     Y         1  False
3    A     X         3   True
4    A     Z         1  False
5    A     Y         2   True
6    B     X         1  False
7    B     Y         1  False
8    B     X         2   True
9    B     X         3   True
```

From there, you can you do a nested `.groupby().cumcount() + 1` of `User` and the series `s` that you created above. Full code:

```
s = ((df.duplicated(subset=(['User', 'Value'])))
       & (df.groupby('User').cumcount() + 1 > df['Cumcount']))
df['Cumcount'] = df.groupby(['User', df.groupby(['User', s]).cumcount() + 1]).cumcount() + 1
df
Out[1]: 
  User Value  Cumcount
0    A     X         1
1    A     X         1
2    A     Y         1
3    A     X         2
4    A     Z         1
5    A     Y         2
6    B     X         1
7    B     Y         1
8    B     X         2
9    B     X         2
```